# How can I make user can only see his contact but admin can sell all contact odoo12

Tags: odoo

I would like to make user can only see his contact but admin can sell all contact. How can I do that?

Comment: Are you aware of Odoo's [Record Rules](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/reference/backend/security.html#record-rules)?

Comment: Do you mean 'his contact' == created or sales person

Comment: @omarahmed Yes.But admin want to sell all

Answer (score 0):

To make salesperson only see his contacts that's mean salesperson field = logged in user

```
        <record id="rule_own_partner" model="ir.rule">
            <field name="name">Own Partners</field>
            <field name="model_id" ref="base.model_res_partner"/>
            <field name="domain_force">[('user_id', '=', user.id)]</field>
            <field name="groups" eval="[(6,0,[ref('sales_team.group_sale_salesman')])]"/>
        </record>
```

and to make admin see all contacts

```
        <record id="rule_all_partner" model="ir.rule">
            <field name="name">All Partners</field>
            <field name="model_id" ref="base.model_res_partner"/>
            <field name="domain_force">[(1, '=', 1)]</field>
            <field name="groups"
                   eval="[(4, ref('sales_team.group_sale_manager'))]"/>
        </record>
```